# Fastest, most efficient way to aggregate a large dataset in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's say I'm measuring the speed over time of a car moving forward on a single axis, with a new measure every 10 minutes.

I have a column in my DataFrame called `delta_x`, which contains how much the car moved on my axis in the last 10 minutes, values are integers only.

Now let's say that I want to aggregate my data, and have only the amount of movement over each hour, but I want to optimize my code as much as possible because my dataset is extremely large, what's the most efficient way to achieve that ?

```
df.head(9)

    date        time    delta_x
0   01/01/2018  00:00   9
1   01/01/2018  00:10   9
2   01/01/2018  00:20   9
3   01/01/2018  00:30   9
4   01/01/2018  00:40   11
5   01/01/2018  00:50   12
6   01/01/2018  01:00   10
7   01/01/2018  01:10   10
8   01/01/2018  01:20   10
```

Currently my solution is to do the following

```
for file in os.listdir('temp'):
    if(file.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_csv(''.join(["./temp/",file]), header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
        df.columns = ['date', 'time', 'delta_x']
        df['hour'] = [(datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M")).hour for x in df['time'].values]
        df = df.groupby(['date','hour']).agg({'delta_x': 'sum'})
```

Which outputs the correct:

```
date        hour   delta_x
01/01/2018  0      59
```

But I was wondering, is there a better, faster and more efficient way, perhaps using NumPy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following packages which are used for speeding up pandas operation

https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter

https://github.com/modin-project/modin